How to reference a collection item that has a dot in it's name Using Make.com
Using Make.com with a webhook that receives data when an invoice is created in another system.
Inside the scenario @ Make.com, normally the referenced data points from the other system are available from the webhook to be selected and used in the subsequent steps of the scenario.  In this case, the Make.com editor doesn't display the items in the collection; I assume because it has a dot in the name of one of the items in the collection.
While trying to reference the collection item that has the dot in the name, it returns nothing.  However, the other item, in this case Action, returns as expected.
Body:
{
“AccountId”:“123456”,
“MessageType”:“Invoice”,
“Parameters”:{
“**Document.Id**”:87654321,
“Action”:“Created”
}
}

I have viewed several different solutions on this site and tried all the different combinations of quotes, brackets, and dots, but nothing has worked so far.

Not sure where or how you tried to reference it, but generally in JavaScript, you need to use object['proper.ty'] syntax to access properties with a dot in the name, see also How to get objects value if its name contains dots?
